# How to select random ID's from database excluding deleted ones?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, random

I have a "banners" table which has image names and paths to image files that will be randomly viewed each time visitor navigates to another page.

banners table consists of banner_id (auto_increment, unique, primary, tinyint), banner_name (varchar) and banner_path (varchar) fields.

Banners table will be editable via a control panel. New banners will be ADDED, some banner will be DELETED after a while, and may be UPDATED. General CRUD operations, you know...

Now... Because of my goal is showing banners randomly, I will need a random number generator function which gives ability to exclude specific ones.

To be more clear,

Let's say my table looks like this:

```
banner_id     banner_name     banner_path
---------     ------------    ------------
1             First Banner    first_banner.jpg
2             Second Banner   second_banner.jpg
3             Third Banner    third_banner.jpg
```

I can get random ID by using PHP function like this easily: `mt_random(1, 3);`

But wait. What if I delete one of these banners?

```
banner_id     banner_name     banner_path
---------     ------------    ------------
1             First Banner    first_banner.jpg
3             Third Banner    third_banner.jpg
```

In this case, as random output becomes "2", what will happen? There is no a "2" banner_id'd row?? So I must exclude DELETED id's from random generator number range. Will this be the best practise? If so, how can I do that?

I'm completly open for any new ideas which will help me to do thing I want to do.

Please help me to figure out this problem...

Thanks

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can live with the small race window, you could do

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*COUNT(*)) AS bannercount FROM banners;
```

and fetch this into `$bannercount`, next run

```
SELECT * FROM banners ORDER BY banner_id LIMIT $bannercount,1
```

Comment: Uhmm.. I'm not so clear with this answer. Can you explain how can this method provide me randomness? :s

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FLOOR(RAND()*4),1' at line 1` 

Doesn't even work at phpMyAdmin SQL window? What am I missing? :s

Comment: Didn't know MySQL would choke on the calculation - moved it into the SELECT phase, works now.

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you. It repeats same result frequently but I think it's about number of rows which is not so big and MySQL random engine, right?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) INTO @offset FROM banners;
SELECT * FROM banners LIMIT @offset, 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just select a random row instead of using PHP to select a random ID to show?

```
SELECT * FROM `banners` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

And if you have an array of ID's to exclude

```
SELECT * FROM `banners` 
WHERE `banner_id` NOT IN (/* array values*/) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: Because thiw is a performance killer: It will fetch ALL banners, calclulate `RAND()` for each of them, then order, then throw away all but one.

Comment: @EugenRieck explained it very vell :)

Answer (score 0):

you will create one array from available ids and generate random numbers from that array